# why we Import createBrowserHistory from history? and why we pass it to the Router like <Router history={variable_name}? please explain me in detail

Tags: reactjs

There is file called`"createBrowserHistory.d.ts"`, what is the use of that file?

And the below code has no error but when i try to run it, it will show blank ? why so?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login.js';
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
// import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
var hist = createBrowserHistory();
ReactDOM.render( 
    <Router  history={hist}>

            <Route path="/" exact component={Home.js} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login.js} />

    </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**login.js code**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Login extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("component did mount");
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log("component will mount");
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                    <h2>I am Login</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Home.js code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from  'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("component did mount");
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log("component will mount");
    }
render(){
    return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Login</li>
                </ul>
                    <link to='/login'>
                    Login
                    </link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Please give me a clear solution which can understand easily. thank you

Comment: Here are some docs that might be helpful: https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md

Answer (score 5):

-
createBrowsweHistory manages the page navigation as par the browser Preference.
the history for the forward and go-back buttons on the top of the browser can be managed through this package.

-why we use it?

not to disturb virtual DOM as it will not render again and again if user uses the browser buttons for the navigation